# JOptionPane trying to retrieve which button is selected

Tags: java, joptionpane

I'm currently trying to get this part of my code to compare which button the user chooses to the button it self. At the moment it automatically displays the else which is Test2.

```
Object usersChoice;

    Object[] options = { "Go on a journey!", "Exit, i'm tired." };
    usersChoice = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Hello Melissa :)", "Sunshine program",
    JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,
    null, options, options[0]);

    if(usersChoice == options )
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Test1");
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Test2");
    }
```

Comment: What is your intended behavior?

Comment: In the if else im going to be putting two functions in there, but I simply wrote two joptions to test it. I want it to be so when the user selects the button "Go on a journey!" it goes into the if statement, else "Exit, i'm tired".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with this code (I've moved the declaration of `usersChoice` for clarity):

```
Object[] options = [...]
Object usersChoice = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog([...])
```

The method `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog()` returns an int. Since that's a primitive, it gets autoboxed to an `Integer`.

Now you have this code:

```
if(usersChoice == options )
```

You are comparing an `Object[]` to an `Object` (more specifically, an `Integer`). That will always be false because they are different types.

Also remember that in Java, using `==` checks for equality on primitives, but `Object`s compared this way will be compared by their memory locations. Use `.equals()` instead to compare `Object`s.